# Looking for examples of how to use "@_*" when doing pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala, operators, pattern-matching

I have been searching for a bit but can not locate any examples that demonstrate the usage of @_* while pattern matching case classes.

Below is an example of the kind of application I am referring to.

```
def findPerimeter(o: SomeObject): Perimeter = o match {
case Type1(length, width) =>
  new Perimeter(0, 0, length, width)
case Type2(radius) =>
  new Perimeter(0, 0, 2*radius, 2*radius)
...

case MixedTypes(group @_*) => {
  \\How could @_* be used to check subpatterns of group?
}
```

}

If someone could show me some examples or point me to a web page that has a few examples that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that something like

```
Type2(3.0) match {
  case t2 @ Type2(radius) => //...
}
```

binds `radius` to the value `3.0` and binds `t2` to the instance of Type2 being matched against.

Using your example:

```
def findPerimeter(o: SomeObject): Perimeter = o match {
  case Type1(length, width) => new Perimeter(0, 0, length, width)
  case Type2(radius) => new Perimeter(0, 0, 2*radius, 2*radius)
  // ...
  // assume that Perimeter defines a + operator
  case MixedTypes(group @ _*) => group.reduceLeft(findPerimeter(_) + findPerimeter(_))

}
```

Here, `group` is bound to the sequence of `SomeObject`s that define the `MixedTypes`.  You can treat is just like a sequence of whatever-the-constructor-args-for-MixedTypes-is.

Answer (score 3):

Programming Scala by Wampler/Payne has [an example](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch03.html#MatchingOnSequences).

Also some another SO question:
[Pattern matching a String as Seq[Char]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740563/pattern-matching-a-string-as-seqchar)

And the Daily Scala blog post on [unapplySeq](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/09/extract-sequences-unapplyseq.html).