# Implicit String to Seq[Char] pattern matching fail

Tags: scala

Warning - this is a code which deals with Codility BinaryGap task - just to warn as this may spoil something to somebody.

I have a piece of code, like

```
@tailrec
def count2(max:Int, count:Int, d:Seq[Char]):Int = d match {
  case '1' :: s => count2(Math.max(max, count), 0, s)
  case '0' :: s => count2(max, count+1, s);
  case Nil => max
}
```

I call it like

```
println(Solution.count2(0, 0, Seq('1', '0')))
println(Solution.count2(0, 0, "10"))
```

It compiles, however the second call does not work - throwing "Match not found 10" And I cannot understand why. There is a [similar question around that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740563/pattern-matching-a-string-as-seqchar) which states, that explicit conversion is needed. However, I feel like I do have one in form of a method parameter type. 
Debugger clearly states that d variable is of type WrappedString - which should do the job. But apparently, it does not.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern matching is working only on a the type `List[Char]` while you are passing an object of type `Seq[Char]`. Therefore you will never actually match on the very first call. The reason it compiles is that match is not exhaustive for `Seq`. It is, however, exhaustive for `List`.

**Update**:

Let me point out two things:

1. The default constructor for `Seq` produces a `List`. So the first example "works."
2. The `String` you've given is implicitly convertable to a `Seq[Char]` but it is not a `List`! Hence, it will give you your match error.

Comment: Therefore you will never actually match on the very first call - thats strange because it does work and produces valid output.
And this is not a course work assignment - its publicly available codility task rather to test their platform than actual coding itself.

Comment: Never means never for Seqs that aren't lists.